# javascript object within object issue

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to get the first object within an object.

I have something like

```
var object = {
     task:{
       config:'auto',
       title :'test'
     },
     prop:'switch',
     time:'5min'
}
```

My problem is task object could be named differently. so it could be

```
var object = {
     task2:{
       config:'manual',
       title :'test2'
     },
     prop:'switch',
     time:'5min'
}
```

I can't use `object.task1.config` because `task` name could changed. The `task` object will always be the first object though.

I want to get the task object no matter what name it has. How do I accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: Could it have other properties than `prop`, `time` or the one you want ?

Comment: no it won't have other properties. I just need to get the first task object.

Comment: @FlyingCat are there other properties in the object that are also objects, or is task the only one?

Comment: Objects properties don't really have a concept of "first" - if you need properties to be in a specific order you have to use an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first property value of an object in modern browsers you could use the [`Object.keys` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys):

```
var myObject = {
    whoTheHellKnows: 'foo',
    notUsed: 'whatever'
};

var firstProperty = myObject[Object.keys(myObject)[0]];
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/J69Mw/)

Edit: if you do not trust the ordering of the properties (which you should not) **AND** the task object is the only nested object in your objects, you can rely on type interrogation to find it:

```
var myObject = {
    task123215452: { dahKey: 'foo' },
    notUsed: 'whatever',
    somethingElse: 42
};

var taskObject;

for (var key in myObject) { 
    if (typeof myObject[key] === 'object' && !(myObject[key] instanceof Array)) {
        taskObject = myObject[key];
        break;
    }
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/J69Mw/1/)

Comment: Is `Object.Keys()` guaranteed to return the keys in the same order they were defined ?

Comment: No, there's no guarantee regarding the order.

Comment: From the docs: "The ordering of the properties is the same as that given by looping over the properties of the object manually."

Comment: @jbabey ...which is implementation-dependent

Comment: @bfavaretto my edit should be order-independent, though it relies on there only being a single nested object literal.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access the first key and you don't know the key name, you should really be using an array instead of an object. Objects don't have the concept of a "first" key.

If that's not an option, you're left with `for..in` or `Object.keys`, which may fail on some JavaScript implementations because the language specification does not enforce the order of object key enumerations. However, in practice, it will work on current browsers, as they all iterate the keys in the order they were declared<sup>[citation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Fdelete#Cross-browser_issues) <strike>needed</strike> thanks to jbabey</sup>.

Comment: [Your citation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Fdelete#Cross-browser_issues): "all major browsers support an iteration order based on the earliest added property coming first"

Comment: Interesting IE edge case mentioned there!